# code: 'invalid-directive-value' with svelte binding

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to bind an input value:

```
const link = {};
...
<input name="url" bind:value={link?.url} />
```

However I get this error:

```
file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/utils/error.js:56
        const error = new CompileError(message);
                      ^

CompileError [ValidationError]: Can only bind to an identifier (e.g. `foo`) or a member expression (e.g. `foo.bar` or `foo[baz]`)
    at error (file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/utils/error.js:56:16)
    at Component.error (file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/Component.js:551:4)
    at new Binding (file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/nodes/Binding.js:50:14)
    at file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/nodes/Element.js:482:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Element (file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/nodes/Element.js:470:19)
    at file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/nodes/shared/map_children.js:86:16
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at map_children (file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/nodes/shared/map_children.js:82:18)
    at new Element (file:///home/ettinger/src/hynt.us/hynt-web/node_modules/svelte/src/compiler/compile/nodes/Element.js:516:19) {
  code: 'invalid-directive-value',
  start: { line: 24, column: 60, character: 494 },
  end: { line: 24, column: 82, character: 516 },
  pos: 494,
  filename: undefined,
  frame: '22:   <form on:submit={submit}>\n' +
    '23:     {data?.status ?? ""}\n' +
    '24:     <div><input name="url" placeholder="Enter url" required bind:value={link?.url} /></div>\n' +
    '                                                                ^\n' +
    '25:     <div>{data?.errors?.url ?? ""}</div>\n' +
    '26:     <div><input name="alias" placeholder="Enter alias (optional)" bind:value={link?.alias}/></div>'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Does anyone know what this error means or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

So its the `?` in `{link?.url}` that was causing the compilation error, removing that and it works fine.